# Loomis and Sternberg Chapter 1 Problem 3.19

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

[image]

The first part of the question is trivial. What is the author asking in the second part and how is it solved? Thanks

Comment: what about the question is not clear? The question is solved by giving a precise definition and using induction (since a super precise definition requires induction).

Comment: $p(T)$ means a sum in the form of $c_nT^n+c_{n-1}T^{n-1}+\cdots+c_1T+c_0I$ where the $c_i$s are scalar coefficients.

Comment: Recall the $T(\alpha)=x\alpha.$ What happens if you apply $T$ to both sides? Do it again. Do you notice a pattern? Since $T^{-1}T(\alpha)=T^{-1}(x\alpha)=\alpha,$ what can you say with regard to $T^{-1}(\alpha)?$ How to handle the case of $p(T)$ should now be clear based on user1551's answer.

Comment: @ChrisLeary user1551 peek-a-boo Thanks everyone! I initially didn’t understand what $p(T)$ is. The result was trivial to show using your explanations